# How do I permanently disable individual notifications in Windows 10 2004?

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I am tired of disabling the same notifications every single day:
[image]

Here you see I flipped the toggle to off. I do this to every single annoying app, yet on the next day they are all on again...

Comment: Deal with and close each notification as they come and then multiple notifications should not happen.  I do not see this.

Comment: Is this machine connected to an AD domain?

Comment: @John I think the problem lies not with Windows. The persistent notifications came from 2 programs, one I don't remember right now, the other one is Macrium Reflect. I disabled the features causing the notifications in each of the programs as a workaround.

Comment: @Ramhound no, it is not connected to any domain, this is my personal machine.